# Click desktop app element using winApp drive

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, winappdriver

I am automating desktop application Using winApp driver similer to selenium driver.
In which I am trying to click a button which don't have name,class name or any unique tag to identify. So i want to click the button where next to next tag having name ICC Base.

Tag Example:
"Custom" ,"button" ,"image","ICC Base" text

Where custom, button, image have no uniform value.

```java
WebElement a = driver.findElementByName("ICC Base");
WebElement btn = a.findElement(By.Xpath("preceding-sibling::button");
```